# Why is Firefox not respecting the standard javascript support element test

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, datetimepicker

I am testing for support of datetime and/or datetime-local elements with this pretty basic javascript test.

```
var delm =document.createElement("input")
delm.setAttribute("type", "datetime");
if (delm.type != "datetime") {
    // do some custom datepicker
}
```

I am also doing this same test with the "datetime-local" element type. In every other browser I tested, I get the expected results.

In Firefox mobile, the `delm.type` becomes "text", so I implement the fallback datepicker. Except that when focusing that field, the native datetime picker pops up!

I got this same bad result using the latest version of Modernizr.

Is there some better way to test for element support?

Comment: so be more diligent: `delm.setAttribute("type", "datetime");` followed by `alert(delm.type)`. Because why assume that case is preserved? *find out what's in that attribute* before testing against it, or force it to whatever case your comparison needs =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, ok fair enough. let's see...

Comment: Firefox mobile returns the type as "text". Same problem.

Comment: Then the question is "is that really what it uses, though". See what `delm.outerHTML` reports back? Also note that in JS, identity testing uses `===`, unless you really want coerced equivalence, which is generally a bad thing to rely on.

Comment: `delm.outerHTML = <input type="datetime">`  I don't really know what to make of that. That doesn't really help, because if I set the type to "dlkfjdf", then `delm.outerHTML = <input type="dlkfjdf">`

Comment: it helps in the sense that we now know FF mobile clearly has a bug. So if there wasn't one (Mattias found it already) this would be the perfect time to file one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a bug in Firefox Mobile.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446510#c30) Although the UI dialog works great, none of the DOM interfaces are currently implemented. In the DOM, an `<input type="datetime" />` still looks and feels like an `<input type="text" />`, with no obvious way to detect it.

Depending on your application, you could make a special case for Firefox Mobile (i.e. browser sniffing, unfortunately). Alternatively, you could *force* the `type` to be `"text"` to make sure that no browser will try to use its own UI for it:

```
var delm =document.createElement("input")
delm.setAttribute("type", "datetime");
if (delm.type != "datetime") {
    delm.type = "text"; // prevent double dialogs
    // do some custom datepicker
}
```

I wish I had a better answer for you...

Comment: I don't _like_ your answer, but you seem to be correct. Forcing the type to "text" is a reasonable approach to squash this bug. Thanks!